# I have a php form, works wonderful, but I can't get the file upload to be optional

Tags: php, forms, file, upload, option-type

thank you for looking at this. I am quite new to the PHP coding side. So basically I have pieced together a form it works. But I want to have the file upload option... well optional.  I've read over many questions/sites but I can't seem to figure it out. So I've come here. I'll post the code below. I'd really like to stick to this code and not have to redo the whole form, for now.

```
    <?php
$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = $phoneErr = "";
$fname = $lname = $email = $phone = "";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

$webMaster="email@email.com"; //email removed on purpose for upload//
$subject="Online Price Request";
$from = stripslashes($_POST['fname'])." ".stripslashes($_POST['lname'])."<".stripslashes($_POST['email']).">";

if (empty($_POST["fname"]))
 {$fnameErr = "First name is required";}
else
 {
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$fname))
   {
   $fnameErr = "Only letters allowed"; 
   }
 }

if (empty($_POST["lname"]))
 {$lnameErr = "Last name is required";}
else
 {
 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lname))
   {
   $lnameErr = "Only letters allowed"; 
   }
 }

if (empty($_POST["email"]))
 {$emailErr = "Email is required";}


if (empty($_POST["phone"]))
 {$phoneErr = "Phone number is required";}
else
 {
 if (!preg_match("/^[-0-9 ]*$/",$phone))
   {
   $phoneErr = "Only numbers are allowed"; }?>   
    <?php

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$dateevent = $_POST['dateevent'];
$garmenttype = $_POST['garmenttype'];
$garmentquantity = $_POST['garmentquantity'];
$garmentsize = $_POST['garmentsize'];
$garmentcolor = $_POST['garmentcolor'];

$garmentstyle = $_POST['garmentstyle']; $imprint1 = $_POST['imprint1'];
$imprint2 = $_POST['imprint2'];
$artworkyes = $_POST['artworkyes'];
$artworkno = $_POST['artworkno'];
$artwork = $_POST['artwork'];
$artworkfile = $_POST['artworkfile'];
$info = $_POST['info'];

    }

$mime_boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x".md5(mt_rand())."x";
$tmp_name = $_FILES['artworkfile']['tmp_name'];
$type = $_FILES['artworkfile']['type'];
$file_name = $_FILES['artworkfile']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['artworkfile']['size']; 
$body = "\n\n First Name: $fname \n\n Last Name: $lname \n\n Phone: $phone \n\n Date of Event: $dateevent \n\n Garment Type: $garmenttype \n\n Garment Style (Numeric): $garmentstyle \n\n Amount of Garment: $garmentquantity \n\n Color of Garment: $garmentcolor \n\n Front Colors: $imprint1 \n\n Back Colors: $imprint2 \n\n Artwork: $artwork \n\n Uploaded Artwork: $file_name \n\n Additional Information: $info";

if (file_exists($tmp_name)){

  if(is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)){

     $file = fopen($tmp_name,'rb');
     $data = fread($file,filesize($tmp_name));

     fclose($file);

     $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
 }

  $headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
     "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
     "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
     " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

  $body = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
     "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
     "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
     "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
     $body . "\n\n";

  $body .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
     "Content-Type: {$type};\n" .
     " name=\"{$file_name}\"\n" .
     //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
     //" filename=\"{$fileatt_name}\"\n" .
     "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
     $data . "\n\n" .
     "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

  if (@mail($webMaster, $subject, $body, $headers))
{    ?>
     <div><center><h1>Request Sent Successfully !!</h1></center></div>
     <div><center><a href="index.html"><h2>Click here to return to the main page.</h2></a></center></div>
     <?php
  }else
  {
     ?>
     <div><center>
       <h1>Error !! Unable to send Request...</h1></center></div>
     <?php }}}    ?>
```

Comment: how could it be optional? You have no `if()`-type logic around where you try to embed the file attachment. Plus, you have absolutely no upload validation and simply assume all uploads succeed. You should also be using Swiftmailer or PHPMailer to generate mime emails. almost all of that mime-related code will simply go away if you start using either package.

Comment: I've tried to add an if(), but honestly I do not know where to, this is my first php run. I've added it in several places and it just gave me back errors when I uploaded to the server I am running it off. if(empty($_FILES['artworkfile']['tmp_name']))} is the right code? if so then that's what I've been using. I am not familiar with Swiftmailer or PHPMailer. Thank you for your comment, more advice would be helpful.